# Generating a parent child array based on URL

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have the following url /dir1/dir2/page.php

I need to generate a an array of the parent->child relation form the above url.

```
/dir1
    |
    |
    /dir2/
        |
        |
        page.php
```

eg :

```
array('dir1'=> array(
        'child' => array( 'dir2' => array(
                    'child' => array( 
                            'page' => array())))));
```

I tried using the recursive function but not able to figure out the logic.
Please let me know if you need some more explanation.

Comment: You look like you are new to SO. So if an answer pleases you, please check the checkbox next to the answer to give the person credit.

Comment: Yes, Matt i have recently joined SO.I will surly do that.

Comment: Honestly your array structure looks somehow unnecessary complex. Is there anything else you want to add to the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a recursive method (sorry for lack of comments, it's late):

```
<?php
$urls = array('/dir1/dir2/page.php', '/dir1/dir3/page');

function url_to_array($url, $array=null) {
    if($array === null) {
        $array = array();
        $url_parts = explode('/', $url);

        return url_to_array($url_parts, $array);
    } else {
        if(count($url)) {
            $item = array_pop($url);
            if($item) {
                if(!$array) {
                    $array = array('page' => $array);
                } else {
                    $array = array($item => array('child' => $array));
                }
            }
            return url_to_array($url, $array);
        } else {
            return $array;
        }
    }
}

$array = array();
foreach($urls as $url) {
    $array = array_merge_recursive($array, url_to_array($url));
}

print_r($array);
?>
```

It prints out:

```
wraith:Downloads mwilliamson$ php recursive.php 
Array
(
    [dir1] => Array
        (
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [dir2] => Array
                        (
                            [child] => Array
                                (
                                    [page] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [dir3] => Array
                        (
                            [child] => Array
                                (
                                    [page] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks matt the solution really worked for me.Now i have one more thing to ask.I have many urls thn from that urls i need to generate a tree of parent and child.

Comment: eg: if i have url1 : /dir1/dir2/page  and url2 : /dir1/dir3/page . so what i want is tht there should be only one key for dir1 and under that there should be dir2 and dir2 sort of tree structure.

Comment: Thanks matt for the code. I have also found out one alternative code it generates tree structure from urls ,it not actually written by me but by the guy name kevin.Here is the url to his blog.http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/convert_anything_to_tree_structures_in_php/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a copy/paste from a forum, so I don't know that it works (I skimmed it, and it looks legit).

```
function getDirectory($path = '.', $ignore = '')
{ 
  $dirTree = array();
  $dirTreeTemp = array();
  $ignore[] = '.'; 
  $ignore[] = '..'; 

  $dh = opendir($path); 

  while (false !== ($file = readdir($dh)))
  {
    if (!in_array($file, $ignore))
    {
      if (!is_dir("$path/$file"))
      {
        $dirTree["$path"][] = $file;
      } else {
        $dirTreeTemp = getDirectory("$path/$file", $ignore);

        if (is_array($dirTreeTemp))
        {
          $dirTree = array_merge($dirTree, $dirTreeTemp);
        }
      } 
    } 
  }

  closedir($dh);

  return $dirTree;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an actual solution that I wrote specifically for this problem. No recursion involved!

This returns the exact same array as you posted in your question.

```
function recursiveArrayFromURL () {
    $parts = array_slice(explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 1);
    $refs = array();
    foreach($parts as $key => $v) {
        // remove extension from last file
        if($key == count($parts) - 1) $v = substr($v, 0, -4);

        $thisref = &$refs[$v];
        if(is_null($thisref)) $thisref = array();

        $parent = end(array_slice($parts, 0, $key - 1));

        if(!array_key_exists("child", $refs[$parent])) $refs[$parent]['child'] = array();
        $refs[$parent]['child'][ $v ] = $thisref; 
    }
    return array_slice($refs, 0, 1);
}
```